# How to avoid duplication of the same query where only one parameter varies?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, code-duplication

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, I have an SQL query similar to this:

```
insert into [Schema].[Table] ([A], [B], [C]) values (@A, 1, @C)
insert into [Schema].[Table] ([A], [B], [C]) values (@A, 2, @C)
                                                         ⁞
insert into [Schema].[Table] ([A], [B], [C]) values (@A, n, @C)
```

Is there a way to avoid writing *n* lines of code or at least make the query more compact, given that the query performance doesn't matter? If the performance would matter, would it be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can utilize a loop for this specific case, ie:

```
declare @counter int
set @counter = 1

while @counter < 10
begin
  insert into [Schema].[Table] ([A], [B], [C]) values (@A, @counter, @C)
  set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better options that this, but SQL Server 2008+ has this syntax for `VALUES`:

```
insert into [Schema].[Table] ([A], [B], [C]) 
values (@A, 1, @C),
(@A, 2, @C),
(@A, 3, @C),
(@A, 4, @C),
...
(@A, n, @C)
```

Another option may be to join to a [numbers table](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html), or use a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28SQL.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Oded, a CTE makes quick work of this:

```
declare @A as DateTime = GetDate()
declare @C as Float = 3.141459265358979323846264338
declare @N as Int = 10

declare @T as Table ( A DateTime, N Int, C Float )

; with Alicia as (
  select 1 as Number
  union all
  select Number + 1
    from Alicia
    where Number < @N )
  insert into @T
    select @A, Number, @C
      from Alicia
      order by Number

select * from @T order by N
```